# Private fields from abstract class cannot be accessed in the subclass

Tags: java

I have class which represents every object in my simple game (player, enemy, beam etc - they all have many commons like speed, position, dmg). So i made class named Thing. Here is how it looks like:

```
public abstract class Thing {
    private Image image;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float speed;
    private final int WIDTH;
    private final int HEIGHT;

    public Thing(String filename, float x, float y, float speed) {
        try {
            Image image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.speed = speed;
        WIDTH = image.getWidth(null);
        HEIGHT = image.getHeight(null);
    }

    //Zwraca ksztalt do sprawdzania czy contains...
    public Rectangle2D getShade() {
        return new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public Point2D getPoint() {
        return new Point2D.Float(x, y);
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

I have extended the class Player:

```
public class Player extends Thing {
    public Player(String filename, float x, float y, float speed) {
        super(filename, x, y, speed);
    }

    public void moveToPoint(Point2D targetPoint) {
        int targetX = (int)targetPoint.getX();
        int targetY = (int)targetPoint.getY();
        if ( ((int)x+20 < targetX+3) && ((int)x+20 > targetX-3) ) {
            return;
        }
        float distanceX = targetX - x;
        float distanceY = targetY - y;
        //Dodanie 20px wymiarow statku
        distanceX -= 20;
        distanceY -= 20;
        //Ustalenie wartosci shiftow
        float shiftX = speed;
        float shiftY = speed;
        if (abs(distanceX) > abs(distanceY)) {
            shiftY = abs(distanceY) / abs(distanceX) * speed;
        }
        if (abs(distanceY) > abs(distanceX)) {
            shiftX = abs(distanceX) / abs(distanceY) * speed;
        }
        //Zmiana kierunku shifta w zaleznosci od polozenia
        if (distanceX < 0) {
            shiftX = -shiftX;
        }
        if (distanceY < 0) {
            shiftY = -shiftY;
        }
        //Jezeli statek mialby wyjsc poza granice to przerywamy
        if ( (((int)x+shiftX < 0) || ((int)x+shiftX > 260)) || ((y+shiftY < 0) || (y+shiftY > 360)) ) {
            return;
        }
        //Zmiana pozycji gracza
        x += shiftX;
        y += shiftY;
    }
}
```

And here is the problem because my IDE underlines x, y and speed fields red and tells they cannot be accessed from Player class. I tried to change them into private and default but there appears an error after that. What am I doing wrong? When i create new object from class which extends Thing I want to copy all fields and init them as it is said in constructor. So how to repair it?

Comment: The word "problem" is not without reason forbidden in titles. If everyone titles his question "Java problem" how would one have a clue what problem it is about by just looking at the title? Try to describe the concrete problem itself in the title instead of using the word "problem" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `getX()`, `getY()` etc., because `x`,`y`, `speed` are `private` variables for class `Thing`.

The fact that `Player extends Thing` doesn't mean Player can access `private` fields. `Thing` provided `public` `get... set...` to access its `private` variables.

Comment: But I dont want to access fields from Thing class. I want to make new fields in Player class. Are we thiking about the same thing? Note that I also tried using protected prefix (so no getters would be needed) and error also appeard

Comment: You haven't defined x,y,speed variables at all in Thing class, you need to define them as you have done in Thing class. By the way what is the motive behind defining them in Player class?

Comment: I changed to protected and now i get another error. Motive is that both player, beam and enemy has speed, x, y, width and height and these fields are always defined in the same way. So i decided to put this code in abstract class so i wont have to copy it in sub-classes

Comment: Changed what to protected? When they are in abstract class and you want to reuse them, then getX... should be the approach (your latest comment is contradicting with previous comment).

Comment: There already exists `getPoint` so there's no need to add anything to the `Thing` class. `Point2D` is probably an inappropriate class to use here for a number of reasons. I would, as usual, suggest an immutable value class to represent the point (using `int` as that seems to be what the game logic is based on).

Answer (score 0):

Change the variables `x`, `y`, and `speed` to protected, or use the accessors `getX()`, `getY()`, `getSpeed()` (`getSpeed()` needs to be added in this case) to solve the access issues.

The error that appeared after you changed them to default was the fact that you're calling `abs(...)` instead of `Math.abs(...)`. Change all instances of `abs(...)` to `Math.abs(...)` to get rid of the new errors.

Comment: I wonder what was the negative for?!